# Convert week number to week (date) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

How can I convert dt.week (which returns the week number) to show the week date? My current code:

`my_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt.week`

Returns:

```
1      22
2      22
3      22
4      22
       ..
176    30
177    30
178    30
179    30
180    30
Name: Date & Time, Length: 181, dtype: int64
```

I would like 22 to appear as 05-25-2020, 23 to appear as 06-01-2020, etc.

Data:

```
0    19732166  2020-05-31  Breakfast   
1     4016406  2020-05-31  Breakfast   
2        1132  2020-05-31  Breakfast   
3    19732166  2020-05-31      Lunch   
4        1009  2020-05-31      Lunch   
..        ...         ...        ...   
176      5749  2020-07-23      Lunch   
177     20037  2020-07-23      Lunch   
178   4159294  2020-07-23      Lunch   
179  20402843  2020-07-23      Snack   
180  23053329  2020-07-23      Snack
```

Comment: Can you show your data ?

Comment: @BEN_YO data added in original question

Comment: If it's a `datetime` object, then, `my_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt.date`?

Comment: if you can do .dt.week can't you just do .dt or or dt.date ?   The week is just a # extracted from a full date obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
pd.to_datetime(my_net_diet_raw['Date & Time']).dt.to_period('w').astype(str).str.split('/').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that `y_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt` is a `DatetimeProperties` object**, you should be able to use `y_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt.date` to access the date (you don't need `y_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt.week`). Read more at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html.

If the above doesn't fit your needs, then, you might want to try this:

**Converting `DatetimeProperties.dt.week` to `DatetimeProperties.dt.date`:**
If you wanted to get the first days of a certain number of weeks, you could do something like this (assuming that `y_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt.week` is a `Series` of integers (like in your question)):

```
datetimes_of_first_day_of_each_week = my_net_diet_raw['Date & Time'].dt.week.apply(lambda week: datetime.strptime(f'2020 {week - 1} 1', '%Y %W %w'))
```

`Series.apply()` allows you to specify a function to compute and return a value for each given value in the original series to construct a new `Series`. Here, it is creating a new `datetime` object (for each week number) where the date is of the first day of the week (Monday, in this case), and finally returning each to create a new `Series`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Is this what you are looking for?

```
    df['DATE']+pd.to_timedelta(6-df['DATE'].dt.weekday, unit="d")
```